# Azure VM Ubuntu 16.04 diks ready bytes spikes

Tags: azure, ubuntu-16.04, azure-virtual-machine

I've several VM running Ubuntu 16.04 using Azure and I notice really high disk activity that make the VM unresponsive for long period of time and sometimes a restart/stop-start is only resolution.

I stopped and started it on friday and came back today seeing low activity during the weekend. When I requested a release to be deployed it immediately spikes in the metric Disk Read Bytes rendering the deployment as a failure. This started last week when I wanted to try the Continous Delivery (preview) feature from Azure portal. I've removed the extensions that was installed when trying to set it up.

What can be the cause of this? Is there any way for me to install some monitoring tool to see what process is reading the h*ll out of my disks.
The Resource health tabs have this message logged

> We are currently unable to determine the health of this virtual
>   machine

[image]

## Technical stuff

### VM

- Standard B1s (1 vcpus, 1 GB memory)
- walinuxagent/xenial-updates,now 2.2.21+really2.2.20-0ubuntu1~16.04.1 amd64 [installed] (*edited)

### Attached disk

- Disk. Premium (SSD) 30 GiB. IOPS limit 120. Throughput limit (MB/s) 25
- Linux - Canonical / UbuntuServer / 16.04-LTS / 16.04.201801260

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplest answer to fix your VM from becoming unresponsive is to up your VM size and increase your disk performance so it can handle the IOP throughput that is being pushed and received. B series VMs can have varying performance by design so that could be another factor.

To better monitor the metrics you can enable guest OS diagnostics to gather data and setup alerts to let you know when things appear out of the ordinary.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/monitor#diagnostics-and-metrics

Comment: At certain occasions I haven't started any operations and my applications arn't using the OS-disk other than just taking space. So it must be some out-of-app process, perhaps internal Azure that is causing this issue. Can it be some diagnostic/monitoring tool that occupies all my IO throughput? I've bumped my staging environments and haven't experience this since. The dev is still running on B and havn't seen this there - yet - either. Crossing fingers